# Catch static 'file not found' errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, webapp2

I have a 'catch-all' regex for an error handler like this:

```
(r'/.*', errors.Error)
```

which is listed *after* all others, in order to match "everything else".

This works as intended to fail gracefully when a page does not exist.

However, I also have a static file directory, uploaded like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /files
  static_dir: files
```

Thus, if I attempt to load a URL in `/files/` that does not correspond to an existing file in that directory, I get an:

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

*Without having to list each file to upload separately*, how can I catch this error; ideally with the same handler `errors.Error` above?

Comment: CV'ers: your constructive comments are welcome..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good way to do this, unfortunately.  The feature request is here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8380&q=type%3DFeature%20error%20404&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

There is no way to configure either a custom handler or a static error page for 404's due to files not being present in a `static_dir`.  The same is true for `static_files` if the URL matches anything under the subpath, which is equivalent to `static_dir`:

```
handlers:
- url: /files/(.*)
  static_files: files/\1
  upload: files/.*
```

The URL path matches the special static handler's URL pattern.  Then the static handler realizes that the requested file doesn't exist.  Control does not return to the routing logic, nor is there an opportunity to customize the static handler's response.  The static handler only returns a generic 404.

If the URL pattern for `static_files` matches exactly the filenames that exist, then URL paths that don't match will fall through to subsequent handlers, including possibly a catch-all at the bottom.  But that's effectively listing all of the static files in the config file individually:

```
handlers:
- url: /files/(foo.png|bar.js|baz.css)
  static_files: files/\1
  upload: files/.*
- url: .*
  script: errorhandler.app

# Or for a static error page:
- url: .*
  static_files: error.html
  upload: error.html
```

Also unfortunately, `error_handlers:` does not help, because it does not yet support customizing 404's.  Notably, the 404 returned by App Engine if none of the `handlers:` match the URL is also generic and can't yet be customized either.

The only way to meet this requirement completely without listing the static filenames in a handler's URL pattern is to not use static files, but instead use an app handler to serve the static data out of application files (and serve the custom 404 message if not found).

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: filehandler.app
```

Comment: That's a shame. I've starred the feature request though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Catching a 404 is as simple as the following line of code

`app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404`

where **handle_404** is a def method that handles the exception + you wouldn't' need the "catch-all" regex anymore.

Take a look at this guide for more details in the "**Exceptions in the WSGI app**" section: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html

Also take a look at `app.yaml`'s ***error_handlers*** parameter. [See more here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually the static file not existing raises `HTTPNotFound`. Adding this to `error_handlers` has no effect.